# When can argv[0] have null?

Tags: c, argv

What I have understand about passing arguments to `main()` from command line is that `argc` has a minimum value of `1` and `argv[0]` will always have the program name with its path in it.

If arguments are provided at the command line, then `argc` will have a value greater than one and `argv[1]` to `argv[argc-1]` will have those arguments.

Now a paragraph at [this link](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html) says that

> `argv[0]` will be a string containing the program's name **or a null string** if that is not available.

Now, how and when can `argv[0]` have null string? I mean program name with its path will always be available so when can it be null?

Writer says that "if that is not available" but when and how it is possible that program name will not be available?

Comment: @Ciro Santilli 烏坎事件2016六四事件 法轮功 - Looking at the asked and answered dates, you'll see that this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336027/why-check-if-argv-null, not the other way around.

Comment: @ShaunHamman Current consensus is to close by "quality": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newb Google keywords on the title.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the `exec` class of calls, you specify the program *name* and program *executable* separately so you can set it to NULL then.

But that quote is actually from the ISO standard (possibly paraphrased) and that standard covers a awfully large range of execution environments from the smallest micro-controller to the latest z10 Enterprise-class mainframe.

Many of those embedded systems would be in the situation where an executable name makes little sense.

From the latest c1x draft:

> The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
>
> The value `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
>
> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program start up.

This means that, if `argc` is zero (and it can be), argv[0] is NULL.

But, even when `argc` is *not* 0, you may not get the program name, since the standard also states:

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.

So, there is no requirement under the standard that a program name be provided. I've seen programs use a wide selection of options for this value:

- no value at all (for supposed security).
- a blatant lie (such as `sleep` for a malicious piece of code).
- the actual program name (such as `sleep`).
- a slightly modified one (such as `-ksh` for the login shell).
- a descriptive name (e.g., `progname - a program for something`).

Comment: I'd swear I just heard someone say, "Warp factor one, Mr. Sulu" when reading "Enterprise-class mainframe"...

Comment: The Morris Worm also changed its `argv[0]` iirc. That worm had a lot of clever bits in it as I am sure you know.

Answer (score 8):

**Runnable POSIX example of `argv[0] == NULL`**

caller.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *argv[] = {NULL};
    char *envp[] = {NULL};
    execve("callee.out", argv, envp);
}
```

callee.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 0 && argv[0] == NULL)
        puts("yup");
}
```

Then:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o caller.out caller.c
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o callee.out callee.c
./caller.out
```

Output:

```
yup
```

**Test existing program with empty argument list**

Here's a wrapper that takes a path as its argument, and runs that as a command with no args:

caller-any.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    char *empty[] = {NULL};
    execve(argv[1], empty, empty);

}
```

Sample usage:

```
./caller-any.out /bin/ls
```

GNU Coreutils tools like `ls` however have a check for `argv[0]` NULL as mentioned at: [Why can the execve system call run "/bin/sh" without any argv arguments, but not "/bin/ls"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673765/why-can-the-execve-system-call-run-bin-sh-without-any-argv-arguments-but-not/36674366#36674366) and `ls` outputs:

```
A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this mailing list](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/213426-argv-0-guaranteed-valid-pointer), `argv[0]` can be null if `argc == 0`.  But they don't explain *when* `argc` might ever be zero.  I would *suspect* `argc` would be zero in situations where an executable was not launched "normally" (i.e. through a command line, `popen`, etc.) -- and indeed, as @paxdiablo mentioned, you can manually set `argv` with the [`exec` family of functions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html), so `argc` could be zero depending on those arguments.

But, in their *Rationale* section:

> Early proposals required that the value of `argc` passed to `main()` be "one or greater". This was driven by the same requirement in drafts of the ISO C standard. In fact, historical implementations have passed a value of zero when no arguments are supplied to the caller of the exec functions. This requirement was removed from the ISO C standard and subsequently removed from this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 as well. The wording, in particular the use of the word should, requires a Strictly Conforming POSIX Application to pass at least one argument to the exec function, thus guaranteeing that `argc` be one or greater when invoked by such an application. In fact, this is good practice, since many existing applications reference `argv[0]` without first checking the value of `argc`.

So there you have it: Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications must have `argc` be greater than zero, but that is otherwise by no means guaranteed.

There's a little more information on the standard regarding `argc` and `argv` in the [Program Startup](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html) section.

Comment: You're summarizing the requirement backwards. Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications *called from other Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications* can depend on `argc>0` and `argv[0] != NULL`.  They must also call `execve` and related functions in a way that maintains that guarantee for the child process.  But nothing stops a malicious user from running your strictly-conforming program with `argc == 0` on typical existing POSIX systems.  If it's setuid or has any other special privileges, either check `argc` or the pointer, or make sure that a segfault on access to `argv[0]` won't break anything.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to imagine platforms where programs do not have names - perhaps the code is simply loaded at startup. On those, argv[0] could I guess be NULL. The C Standard certainly allows an argc value of zero, and says that argv[argc] shall be NULL.