# How to get executable name in Qt

Tags: qt

I run a Qt application, what I want to know is this running binary file name.

Answer (score 99):

I must (partially) disagree with the other comments that it is not a Qt question: There is a Qt method [`QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationFilePath) which gives the directory+filename of the executable.

On Linux this will try to use `/proc`, and on Windows perhaps `GetModuleFileName()`. According to the docs it will fall back to `argv[0]`.

You could then use `QFileInfo` to split it into an executable name and a directory.

```
QFileInfo(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()).fileName()
```

Comment: +1. And for the application directory, you can use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`.

Comment: I got: ``QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first``

Comment: qApp->applicationFilePath();

Comment: Thanks @Cameron. Was looking for that. :D

Comment: `QApplication a(argc, argv); QString appPath = a.applicationFilePath();`

Answer (score 3):

The Qapplication parses the commandline arguemnts, the first entry is the name of the executable - this is roughly the same as argv[0] in standard C but has a few extra complexities on windows if you have a Unicode build or if the application is started as a service

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Answer (score -2):

Again not really a Qt question. To find the name of the binary file executed it would be something like.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cout << argv[0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure as to why your concern about it being a Qt question is relevant. The OP is simply stating the environment they're using, no different to if they had said "Linux" or Windows" or, for that matter, "C++". It's extra information which can help target the answers. In this particular case, it's useful because Qt provides a *much* better way to get this info - as per the ISO standard, `argv[0]` is not required to actually hold *any* useful information about the executable. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794150/when-can-argv0-have-null/2794171#2794171 for details.