# How to find the installation directory of a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt based application that works for both Mac and Windows.  When the user installs the software it also installs a folder containing a bunch of HTML documentation pages. How I can find the location of the program's installation so that when the user tries to open Help from within the application, they're brought to `index.html`.

My program installs in the normal locations for Windows and Mac.  On Mac, my program installs to `/Users/username/Applications/MyProgram` where `MyProgram` is a folder containing "MyProgram.app" and the "Doc" folder.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
    docPath = executablePath + "/Doc/index.html";
#elif Q_OS_WIN
    docPath = executablePath + "/Doc/index.html";
#endif

    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(docPath));
```

So, my ultimate question is, what should `executablePath` be?  Further, this assumes the user could install the program elsewhere besides the default location or that the program could be launched from a shortcut.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get executable name in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515602/how-to-get-executable-name-in-qt)

Comment: Isn't QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath ) do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use:

```
QString QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() [static]
```