# How to convert Qt file path from resource to absolute path?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, path, qt-resource

I need to receive the absolute file path like

`C:/Users/Dima/YandexDisk/_Application/WeldAnalysis/ExperimentDefaults.xlsx`

from path of QRC file like

`:/Data/ExperimentDefaults.xlsx`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `qrc` is itself a file and a collection of resource files embedded to executable files and no longer mapped to OS file system. Even if you can see file paths in that `qrc` file they supposed to be all compacted in one collective resource file.

Comment: If the resource file dir. is the one of the application itself then this might help: [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) and, even better, its `static`. I found this in [SO: How to find the installation directory of a Qt application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057482/how-to-find-the-installation-directory-of-a-qt-application).

Comment: I think you can't because data is compiled into the binary, according to the [Qt resource doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resources are packed all together into the QRC file, they are not exposed to the filesystem, thus they cannot be converted to a standard path; it is like accessing a file inside a zip file.

What are you willing to do with such file path? `QFile` can deal with resource paths (`":/..."`) and open such files, but other file handling APIs don't (such as C's `fopen` or C++'s `std::ifstream`). Also, and for the same reason, non-Qt application won't be able to open such files if passed as a parameter.

Options you have include:

- opening the file using `QFile` and read it using related Qt classes (given you are dealing with an Excel file I think it doesn't worth the effort, unless you have some library to read it from a memory buffer).
- copying the file out of the resources container to a temporary directory (you can use [`QTemporaryDir`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporarydir.html) to create one), and use the file from there:

  ```
  QTemporaryDir tempDir;
  if (tempDir.isValid()) {
    const QString tempFile = tempDir.path() + "/yourfile.xlsx";
    if (QFile::copy(":/yourfile.xlsx", tempFile)) {
      // your file is now extracted to the filesystem
    }
  }
  ```

Only be aware that when `tempDir` is destroyed, the temporary directory is also deleted, therefore your file. You can avoid this by disabling the [auto-remove](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtemporarydir.html#setAutoRemove) feature: `tempDir.setAutoRemove(false)` and manually deleting the temporary directory when you finish with the extracted file.