# How to Link .csv Files With the Release version of my Qt App?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My Qt Project uses .csv(not my choice) files to save and load data from ,as i am looking to deploy the app , how do i add these files into the release version and what changes to my code should i do ?

right now i am using QFile and giving it the full path to each file like so :

```
QFile Fich1("C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/MyWork/QtProject/Bibliotheque/Arrays.csv");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to ship CSV files as part of your application, one good way to do it is to use Qt's [resource-file system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html); then they will be compiled into your app so there's no chance of them getting lost/modified/moved.

OTOH if you want to ship CSV files with your app but as separate files (e.g. so that the user can see and load them using a file dialog), then you can package them together with the executable, and then use [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057482/how-to-find-the-installation-directory-of-a-qt-application) as the default directory for the QFileDialog to present to the user.

Comment: I tried adding them as resource-files but the data saved in an execution is lost when executing again.

Comment: Right, application installs are generally considered read-only.  If you need to save data you should save it to somewhere writeable, such as to the user’s home folder.  The Qt QstandardPaths API can help suggest a suitable place to save your data:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#details