# executing a process with argc=0

Tags: c, integer-overflow, argv, argc

Is it possible to execute a process whose argc = 0? I need to execute a program but it is extremely important for its argc to be equal to 0. Is there a way to do that?
I tried to put 2^32 arguments in the command line so that it appears as if argc = 0 but there is a maximum limit to the number of arguments.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? I mean, maybe there's another, simpler way to do it.

Comment: What is your operating system, and how are you executing this process? Is it user-activated or are you calling from another process?

Comment: Can't you just set `argc = 0` as the first line of `main()`?

Comment: also, this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794150/when-can-argv0-have-null

Comment: I have no control over the source code. But I know that in the source code, it exits if argc != 0. I am  on linux ubuntu. I can activate it or I can call it from another process.

Comment: Thanks Aziz for the link, i think it might help

Comment: You could modify the binary with a debugger/hex editor and that would make really short work of it.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a program that breaks if `argc != 0`. That kind of implies that the person who developed it didn't even try running it once, let alone do any real testing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can write a program that calls [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) directly; that allows you to specify the command-line arguments (including the program name) and lack thereof.

Comment: Great, it works. But any idea how to pass arguments and still leave argc=0

Comment: `argc` indicates the number of arguments (plus one, for the program name), so no, that's not possible.

Answer (score 12):

You may use linux system call ***execve()***.

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

You may pass the **filename** of executable and a null pointer as the **argv[]** to execute the binary and the **argc** will be zero.

It is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *argv[] = { NULL };
    execv("./target", argv);
    // execv is correct, look up https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv
    return 0;
}
```

And the *strace* result is:

```
execve("./target", [], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
```

You could use **envp[]** to pass the arguments you defined anyways.

Furthermore, you could use assembly language to reach your goal (argc == 0 but you still need to pass arguments). I assume that you are using a 32-bits x86 environment.

The concept is that:

- store **0x0b** ($SYS_execve) into **%eax**
- put the **address of argv[]** into **%ebx**
- put the **address of envp[]** into **%ecx**
- then use **int 0x80** to do a system call

The memory structure is shown below:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+     
|               +----------------------------------|-----+
v               v               v------------------|-----|-----+
[arg_0][\0][...][arg_1][\0][...][arg_2][\0][...][ptr0][ptr1][ptr2][\0]
                                                ^
                                                |   (argv[] = NULL)
                                                +--- envp
```

I am wondering that if you were doing the lab assignment of the course provided by Prof. Taesoo Kim (GATech).
Course Link: https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/cs6265

Or is it a hacker CTF (catch-the-flag contest) problem?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a C program that spawns/execs the other program with no argv, like:

```
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
{
    pid_t pid;
    char* zero_argv[] = {NULL};
    posix_spawn(&pid, "./that_app", NULL, NULL, zero_argv, envp);

    int status;
    waitpid(&pid, &status, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be undefined behavior?

Comment: @user : Not really. The standard treats `argc` and `argv[0] == 0` as a perfectly fine situation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794150/when-can-argv0-have-null).