# Can argv[0] contain an empty string?

Tags: c, argv

In any C program, the command line argument `argv[0]` points to the name used to invoke the program. Is there any circumstance in which it will point to an empty string `""`?

An example code snippet for such a case would be a good reference.

Comment: Why not design your program so it works regardless? Or use a runtime assertion.

Comment: Better to call it an empty string; null string can too easily be confused with a null pointer.

Comment: related: NULL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794150/when-can-argv0-have-null/42290873#42290873

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's implementation defined. §5.1.2.2.1 abridged:

> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>     `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>     implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>     intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>     from elsewhere in the hosted environment. [...]
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>     represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>     program name is not available from the host environment. [...]

So if `argc` is greater than zero, it's quite the *intention* that `argv[0]` never be an empty string, but it could happen. (Note that with `argc` equal to `n`, `argv[0]` through `argv[n - 1]` are never null and always point to a string. The string itself may be empty, though. If `n` is zero, `argv[0]` is null.)

In practice, of course, you just need to make sure the platforms your targetting behave as needed.

Comment: So in fact if `argv[0][0]` may be 0 `argv[0]` may 'be' empty.

Comment: @alk: `argv[0]` is never null when `argc` is greater than zero, but it may point to an empty string.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You name it ... ;-)

Comment: @GMan Thanks for your answer. Could you please let me know from where you get the C specification? f.e. Where do you get the info about 5.1.2.2.1 from?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is the latest draft of the C99 standard.  [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the latest *available* draft of the recently published 2011 standard.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

The C language standard explicitly allows for the possibility that `argv[0]` can be a null pointer, *or* that it can point to an empty string (`""`).  N1256 5.1.2.2.1p2:

> The value of **argc** shall be nonnegative.
>
> **argv[argc]** shall be a null pointer.
>
> [...]
>
> If the value of **argc** is greater than zero, the string pointed to
>   by **argv[0]** represents the *program name*; **argv[0][0]** shall be
>   the null character if the program name is not available from the host
>   environment. If the value of **argc** is greater than one, the strings
>   pointed to by **argv[1]** through **argv[argc-1]** represent the
>   *program parameters*.

On Unix-like systems, programs are invoked by one of the `exec()` family of functions (`execl()`, `execlp()`, etc.), which allow the caller to specify exactly what arguments are passed to the `main()` function.  (It's even possible to invoke a program in ways that violate the requirements imposed by the C standard.)

Note that the standard says that `argv[0]` (assuming it's neither null nor empty) "*represents* the program name".  The standard is deliberately vague about *how* it represents the program name.  In particular, it needn't provide a name by which the program can be invoked (since the standard doesn't even require that programs can be invoked by name).

Comment: It can't be null, just empty. The previous paragraph requires that each `argv` point to a string (and that the last is null). A crappy implementation could supply them all with empty strings, but not all null.

Comment: If `argc == 0`, then `argv[0]` is a null pointer.  (I hadn't quoted that part when you wrote your comment.)

Comment: It wasn't. I have upvoted, though, since our answers are similar.

Comment: @KeithThompson +1 for mentioning the `exec()` family of functions! Thanks!!

Comment: So do we simply assume the callers of `exec` invoked it according to the standard, program vulnerability aside @KeithThompson?

Comment: @user129393192 I hadn't really thought about it before, but if a program assumes that its `argc` and `argv` are initialized in a conforming manner, using `exec*()` to invoke it could create a security hole. I haven't worked out the details. I'll note that none of the `exec*()` functions take `argc` as an argument; they all compute it from the actual argument vector. (Which eliminates one possible security hole I had thought of.) Probably most programs just assume the arguments are valid, but a sensitive program should allow for other possibilities.  I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528692/manipulating-argv-assumptions-and-language-loopholes) I made about it @KeithThompson

Comment: @user129393192 I did some experiments on Ubuntu and a couple of other systems (FreeBSD, Windows/Cygwin, Android/Termux). I was unable to invoke a program with `argv[0] == NULL`. At worst, either `argv[0]` points to an empty string or the `execl()` call failed, depending on the system. I don't see a way to exploit a security hole using the `exec*()` functions, as long as the target program is able to handle an empty (non-`NULL`) `argv[0]`.

Comment: I'm able to notice strange behavior when invoking `exec` without a `NULL` at the end and also strings without a `\0`. Tested MacOS. @KeithThompson

Comment: Calling `exec*()` without a trailing null pointer has undefined behavior. There's pretty much no way to guard against that. (In at least some cases, gcc warns about such a call.)

Answer (score 7):

Other replies have quoted the C standard and shown that `argv[0]` and can be `NULL` or it can be the empty string (`""`). You should write your program with the assumption that this can happen, because otherwise you are creating a (small) security risk. It's easy to invoke your program and set `argv` to anything an attacker wants. As proof, consider the following two programs. The first one, `echoargv.c` prints out the contents of `argv`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    exit(0);
}
```

The second one, `argv0`, invokes any other program and lets the user specify the other program's argv:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void) execv(argv[1], argv+2);
    perror("execv");
    exit(1);
}
```

(This is a Posix-specific version. Non-standard environments may need changes.)

Here's how to use them:

```
$ gcc -o echoargv echoargv.c 
$ gcc -o argv0 argv0.c 
$ ./argv0 ./echoargv 
$ ./argv0 ./echoargv ''
argv[0] = ""
$ ./argv0 ./echoargv 'this is fun' 'it is fun indeed'
argv[0] = "this is fun"
argv[1] = "it is fun indeed"
$
```

The first run of `argv0` sets `echoargv`'s `argv[0]` to be NULL.
The second run makes it be the empty string.
The third run is there just for fun: note how `argv[0]` doesn't need to have
anything to do with the actual name of the program.

How can this bite you? If, for example, you blindly print out the name of your program in a usage message:

```
printf("usage: %s [options] [FILE]...\n", argv[0]);
```

Better:

```
const char *program_name = "some default name"; /* (global) variable */
if (argv[0] && argv[0][0])
    program_name = argv[0];
printf("usage: %s [options] [FILE]...\n", program_name);
```

If you don't do this, an attacker can cause your program to segfault at will, or might get your program to report entirely wrong things to the user.

Comment: +1 for the awesome example! It was indeed a lot of fun reading your post!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

argv[0] can be null in C, for example if you directly invoke a main function (with some tricks can be done in C). I don't know if C++ allows direct main invocation.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking about `argv[0]` referring to an empty string (`""`, `{'\0'}`), but to `argv[0]` being `NULL`?

Comment: @alk The OP is about empty/null string and not `argv[0]=NULL`

Comment: C++ does not allow you to call `main()`; C does.

Comment: if can be null then can be empty too (\0). The core of the answer is "when main is not invoked by system". An example ? well you can write a main in C which calls itself recursively without passing argv. in C main is just a function. However I think it's bad damn bad practice to invoke main directly. But we're not talking about good or bad practices, are we? See GMan & Keith answers for details about it. They're better than mine (they actually give refs).

Comment: @BigMike +1 for mentioning direct invocation of `main()`. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: just tested with a MS compiler, C++ doesn't allow it. IMHO is a good design choice. in 10+ years of C programming I've seen direct main invocation just once, and I'm still wondering why... but was in the code of a so defined genius so I didn't had the chance to ask or argue.

Comment: Yes, if you call `main` recursively in C, you can pass any garbage values you like. Something like `argc == 2, argv[1] == NULL` is likely to break any normal argument processing. But that's just a bug in your code. You can safely make assumptions about `argc` and `argv` *in the initial invocation of `main`*.