# Manipulating argv (assumptions) and language loopholes

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, arguments, command

When parsing through argv, referring to

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {}
```

I understand that `argv[argc] == NULL` according to the standard, but is it guaranteed that `argv[i] != NULL` where `i < argc`?

In other words, if I perform `argv[i][0]` where `i < argc`, am I guaranteed to not segfault, because `argv[i] != NULL`?

I think that programs could break the `argv` rules, consider these:

```
execlp("malicious_program", "ls", NULL); // program name not in argv[0]
execlp("ls", "ls", NULL, "-al", NULL); // NULL prior to end
execlp("ls", "ls"); // no NULL at end
```

Does the operating system provide safeguards (I think it could simply calculate `argc` from the number of arguments to `exec`), and if not, does that mean that these assumptions cannot safely be made?

When writing my own program, can I therefore use an idiom such as:

```
if (*argv[i] == NULL) break; // infinite loop if no NULL terminator, miss args if NULL middle
```

This last bit is where my question stemmed from.

Answer (score 2):

```
execlp("malicious_program", "ls", NULL); // program name not in argv[0]
```

There's nothing wrong with this. Many programs can be run with different `argv[0]` values, and they use this as a flag to execute differently.

For example, if a shell is run with the first character of `argv[0]` being the `-` character, it executes as a login shell; this is a historical artifact of there not being a standard for arguments to shells, but the login system needs a way of telling the shell that it should operate in login mode.

On some systems, `sh` and `bash` are the same program; it checks `argv[0]` to determine whether to enable bash extensions.

If `telnet` is executed with some other `argv[0]`, it's taken to be the destination hostname; this allows you to make symlinks to `telnet` with the name of a server, and use them as a shortcuts.

Programs that don't make any special use of `argv[0]` (the vast majority) completely ignore it. Putting a "malicious" value there will have no effect.

Why would `malicious_program` care that you put `ls` in `argv[0]`? Did you write that backwards, and intend this:

```
execlp("ls", "malicious_program", NULL);
```

```
execlp("ls", "ls", NULL, "-al", NULL); // NULL prior to end
```

Any arguments after `NULL` will be ignored, because the `NULL` argument is how `execlp()` determines where the end of the arguments is. Variadic argument lists don't provide any way for the function to determine the actual number of arguments. So there's no way for any argument before `argc` to be null, because the null value determines the value of `argc`.

```
execlp("ls", "ls"); // no NULL at end
```

This will cause undefined behavior. Without `NULL`, `execlp()` doesn't know how many arguments there are (see above), and it will try to access nonexistent arguments into `argv`.

As for whether it's safe to access these strings, I think it should always be. When `argv` is constructed by the program loader, it constructs a brand new set of strings, it doesn't simply pass along the pointers that were provided to `exec*()`. The actual layout of `argv` in memory is a single block of memory, with each argument consecutively allocated. E.g. if `argv` is

```
argv[0] = "ls"
argv[1] = "ls"
argv[2] = "filename"
argv[3] = NULL
```

the memory holding all the arguments will look like:

```
ls\0ls\0filename\0\0
```

and the elements of `argv` are pointers into this block.

So these pointers will never be invalid, they will always point into this block. The strings themselves may be meaningless, of course. In the case where you don't provide a `NULL` argument, it will copy garbage strings into `argv`.

Comment: How about something like `char str[] = { 'a' }; execlp("ls", "ls", str, NULL);`. I find that it is undefined in that the byte `\0` will show up randomly so you get varying results with different executions. As someone on the receiving end of `argv`, do I simply treat it with the expectation of it being proper?

Comment: This is also undefined behavior. The arguments have to be strings, which means they have to have null terminators.

Comment: So as someone on the receiving end, do I simply assume the caller invoked me properly?

Comment: Yeah, there isn't really anything you can do. The same is true of *every* function.

Comment: Most likely a segmentation violation will happen when they're calling `execlp()` if they give invalid arguments, so it will never start the new program at all.

Comment: I mean. Typically functions return an error if invoked improperly, in my experience. It seems like the undefined behavior here spills into the callee. I'm wondering if certain program vulnerabilities could be exposed in this way.

Comment: If there's an invalid pointer in the argument list, `execlp()` will detect it and return an error. But the garbage could accidentally be valid, and it can't tell. That's the problem with undefined behavior, it's not always possible to detect.

Comment: Yes right. I've found that on MacOS, `execlp(...)` with exactly 5 arguments and no `NULL` produces an `EFAULT` (which is strange, because there are no bad addresses), but for example, with 3 arguments, it does not, but fills the argument list up until 5, with a trailing `NULL`. It also doesn't catch bad, non `\0` terminated strings in any case.

Comment: Why do you think there are no bad addresses? It's reading past the end of the argument list, which contains arbitrary data, which may include bad addresses.

Comment: It's purely accidental that you get an error with 5 arguments, but not with 3. When there's undefined behavior, ANYTHING can happen.

Comment: I'm still wondering about the security implications of this. You can see my question was "can this safely be assumed" that the arguments are in standard conformant form.

Comment: I've added some more explanation to the end of the answer.

Comment: Well for example, couldn't you invoke undefined behavior in the callee via calling `exec*` without a `NULL` end or including a string without `\0` end?

Comment: The UB will be in the caller, not the callee. In the caller, it will search for a null terminator, and copy everything until that into the callee's copy of `argv`.