# Why am I getting Segmentation fault: 11 in this code

Tags: c++

I have an issue with C++ code. I want to pass argument to my code, but sometimes it will be empty. My code is very simple.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;

}
```

What I want is to show empty argument in case it is not provided. What I get is

```
./main
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: If you're expecting parameters passed to your program in 1st place check these are accessible.

Comment: BTW: `argv[0]` is the program name used to call the executable.

Comment: @kelahcim your edit ruined the question. It no longer exhibits the original problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have changed my code to show how did it look in a first place.

Comment: @kelahcim thank you for doing that second edit.   Btw: your code is still *theoretically* broken, since there's no hard guarantee that `argc` cannot be `0`, and if it is you still read an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess I have to check whether first argument exists as well? BTW - is it possible that argc can be 0? "πάντα ῥεῖ" said argv[0] is program name. Is it possible to run program that has no name?

Comment: @kelahcim https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794171/5910058

Comment: We do not include answers in questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure that two arguments are actually present in `argv` before reading them.
 Reading an uninitialized variable is [undefined behaviour](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc >= 2) {
        std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above would be OK, since `argc` tells you the number of elements in `argv` and the code above then only reads them if there is actually two or more elements to read.

Comment: @kelahcim _"Thanks! It works!"_ By chance probably. I am pretty sure that's not what you want finally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If OP wants something else then a new question should be asked about that other thing. I believe this answers OPs question as stated. My crystal ball does not answer when I ask it what OP wants beyond what was specifically asked.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have changed my code (take a look at the source inside question).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In what way?